# Django: How to modify the same field in other entries sharing the same Foreign Key?

Tags: python, django

I have two models, let's say Book and Author, as follow:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author')
    latest_book = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Now when I create a new book linked to an author, the "latest_book" field will be automatically set to True, which is fine so far...

For exemple, let's say I have an author with a trilogy: Book1, Book2 and Book3 - Book3 being the latest.

I have two problems:
1 - How to set the "latest_book" field of Book1 and Book2 to false when Book3 is being saved?
2 - If Book3 is being deleted, how to set the "latest_book" field of Book2 to true?

Also I was using a method before, but the problem was that I was not able to use list_filter from the BookAdmin to display only the latest books from all authors, as I never found how to list_filter on method results...
And I need to do this filtering, so I try now by using model field

Comment: Have you tried **Signal** or **DateTimeField** instead of BooleanField ?

Comment: What happens when an Author releases two books at the same time?

Comment: I am new to Django, and I never used **Signal**.
I am already using a **DateTimeField** for the published_date, but I would like to use a BooleanField as a flag in addition...

Comment: Only one book as to be the latest, so even if two books are published the same day, I can adjust the time in addition, which is fine. I want to see only one latest_book per author.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, you don't store the latest book, you can just have it as a method or property of the author that can do a query to retrieve it

```
def latest_book(self):
    return self.book_set.order_by('published_date').first()
```

Storing logic into your database is a bad idea, it should only store data.

Comment: Yes, I am using this method in my AuthorAdmin, and it is working fine.
So in AuthorAdmin, I can see the list of Authors, and the latest_book for each of them.
What I would like to do now, is to have a flag in the **BookAdmin**, indicating if the book is a latest_book or not, and when I add or delete a book, to automatically move this flag.
Also, I want to be able to filter the BookAdmin to see only books flagged as latest_book.
Is it any way we can list_filter method results? If so, I could use it for the BookAdmin as well...

Comment: @Gerald - you could still have a (convoluted) method on the book - `self.author.book_set... == self` but I'm not sure how much you'd actually need it

Comment: @Saryse - You are suggesting a logic test, but I am not sure to understand how I should use it? It is still to define the latest_book flag in the BookAdmin, right? If so, I found out how to do it, but then I cannot use list_filters to display only the books with this flag... As it is not part of a tuple. That is why I was looking for a way of storing the flag as a tuple directly. I read some stuff about the save_related method... Do you think it will allow me to alter the fields of others books sharing the same foreign key (identifying the author)?